# Find a and b such that the line $10ex + 10y = 0$ will be a tangent of the curve $ y = ae^{1/(x-1)} - b$ at $x = 2$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

How do I solve this, it seems very simple, yet when I try it turns impossible because I have no idea how to continue:
$$
10ex+10y=0 \\
ex+y=0\\
y=-ex\\
f(x) = -ex\\
f(2)=-2e
$$
And now? I am not sure if this is the right path to solving this so far, and as for the next steps I think I need to find the derivative of the 2nd line. I end up with $$y =- ae^{\frac{1}{x-1}}\frac{1}{(x-1)^2} $$ and I have no idea how to continue from here, I think I am supposed to use $-2e$ somewhere, but I don't understand how that will help me find $a$ or $b$, considering $b$ is gone now?

Comment: Hint: Calculate the tangent to the provided function at $x=2$ in terms of $a,b$.

Comment: Can you check if my edits are correct?

Comment: @SewerKeeper most of them were, I approved them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=ae^{\frac{1}{x-1}}-b$$

then for $x>1$
$$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}(f(x)+b)$$

the equation of the tangent at $x=2$ is

$$y=f'(2)(x-2)+f(2)$$
$$=-(f(2)+b)(x-2)+f(2)$$
$$=-(f(2)+b)x+3(b+f(2))-b$$
$$=-ex$$
thus

$$f(2)+b=ae=e$$
and
$$3ae-b=0$$
therefore
$$a=1\;;\;b=3e$$

Comment: Why is it exactly x > 1 and not just x =/= 1?

Comment: @congruencer we are near the point $x=2$.